# Angular 6 - Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'Operator Function<{}, {}>?

Tags: angular

I create a new project with Angular 6 but when I try to add my http request I get an error with the .subscribe.
I can only find solution for prior versions of Angular.
Can someone help out please?

Product service

```
import {Injectable} from "@angular/core";
import {Http,Response} from "@angular/http";
import {Observable} from "rxjs";
import { map, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable()
export class ProductService {

    constructor(public http: Http) { }

    public getProducts(dataURL:string){
        return this.http.get(dataURL)
            .pipe(map((res:Response) => res.json())),
            catchError((error:any) => Observable.throw(error || 'Server error'));
    }
}
```

category.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {ProductService} from "../../services/products.service";
import {Product} from "../../model/product";
import {CartService} from "../../services/cart.service";
import {Router} from "@angular/router";

@Component({
    selector: 'app-category',
    templateUrl: './category.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./category.component.css']
})
export class CategoryComponent implements OnInit {
    public products:Array<Product>;
    private sub;
    constructor(
         private productService:ProductService,
         private cartService:CartService,
         private router: Router
    ) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.load();
    }
    load = () => {
       this.sub = this.productService.getProducts('./assets/mock-data/products.json')
            .subscribe(res => {
                this.products = res;
            })
    };
    addToCart = (product) => {
        this.cartService.addToCart({product,quantity:1})
    };
    ngOnDestroy() {
        this.sub.unsubscribe();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

move the `catchError` inside the `pipe` function. `catchError` is a rxjs operator. operators need to wrap around `pipe` functions in order to use it.

```
 return this.http.get(dataURL)
  .pipe(
     map((res:Response) => res.json()),
     catchError((error:any) => Observable.throw(error || 'Server error'))
  ),
```

Comment: Wow thank you so much !! I have been on this for too long haha